# External application cant be found in tex2pix

Tags: python, tex

I am trying to convert latex into an image. Using tex2pix I get the following errors. I do have pdflatex installed along with latex and python-pdf. All packages are up to date. The error summarizes to not finding the required external packages for tex2pix. Particularly pdflatex.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\calculator\virt\lib\site-packages\tex2pix.py", line 173, in mkpdf
     raise ExternalPkgException("Cannot find packages needed to build PDFs")
   File "C:\calculator\virt\lib\site-packages\tex2pix.py", line 42, in __init__
     Exception.__init__(msg)
 TypeError: descriptor '__init__' requires a 'Exception' object but received a 'str'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\calculator\main.py", line 52, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "C:\calculator\virt\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 955, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\calculator\virt\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\calculator\virt\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 339, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\calculator\virt\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 383, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\calculator\virt\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 334, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\calculator\virt\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 302, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\calculator\virt\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 727, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1191, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\calculator\virt\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 55, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "C:\calculator\calculator.kv", line 29, in <module>
     on_release: root.number()
   File "C:\calculator\main.py", line 43, in number
     image.add_widget(Image(Renderer(latex(sp.sin(x))).mkjpg()))
   File "C:\calculator\virt\lib\site-packages\tex2pix.py", line 222, in mkjpg
     self.mkpdf()
   File "C:\calculator\virt\lib\site-packages\tex2pix.py", line 191, in mkpdf
     raise Exception("pdflatex could not be run: PDF, PNG, and JPEG format modes cannot work")
 Exception: pdflatex could not be run: PDF, PNG, and JPEG format modes cannot work
```

Comment: Haven't worked with any of these libraries to be much of a help but reading the error there is an error for an invalid argument, is it within the library or did you double-check your code?

Answer (score 0):

#### External requirements for tex2pix

The documentation of [*tex2pix* on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/tex2pix/) requires:

> applications on your system like *latex*, *pdflatex*, *bibtex*, *dvips*, *ps2eps*, and *convert*.

So your system should probably have those executables on path.

#### Analysis of the `ExternalPkgException`

See also from the stacktrace [line 173](https://gitlab.com/agbuckley/tex2pix/-/blob/master/tex2pix.py#L173) of the source-code.
Before raising this `ExternalPkgException("Cannot find packages needed to build PDFs")` it calls `check_pdf_pkgs` which does following:

> Test for pdflatex if we need to make a PDF

#### Do you have `pdflatex` on your system

Test yourself on the command-line (for Linux/Unix/MacOS:

`which pdflatex` to locate the executable or simply call `pdflatex` to test the presence

#### Install *pdflatex*

If you don't have *pdflatex* installed, try installing it:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49569/where-to-download-pdflatex-exe#49570

Comment: Yes I do.  I installed everything on my virtual environment.